# "The following object is masked _by_ .GlobalEnv" after using attach() in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of age named *hwk*. This dataset has attribute number, age, row, treatment. And I try to use `attach(hwk)` to put all private variables into global. However, it shows an error message about `attach(hwk)`. I wonder to know how can I solve this problem?
[the dataset of ages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JbOc.png)

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HvoJ.png)

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue with given information.

Comment: NEVER use `attach`. It causes more problems than it solves. You can use `with` to cut down on typing, or simply add the `hwk$` to variable names. Also note that many functions (like `lm`, `aggregate`, and `xtabs`) have a "data" argument that you can/should use instead.

Comment: I agree with @lmo. Never use attach. The error message indicates you've already used it a few times and have not be using `detach()` after you are done. It also looks like you've tried to modify a variable after you've attached which created a variable in your global environment since you can't modify values that are attached.